# Integration by Parts Series

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been having trouble with this question in my recent revision. I've tried adding the $I_n$ and $(n-1)I_{n-2}$ integrals together, directly, but I've always ended up with a progressively decreasing integral, such as $I_{n-4}, I_{n-6}$ and so on.

How would I do this question effectively?

Thankyou in advance[image]

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts (IPP)?

Comment: Yes I have, I've been letting $2x e^{x^2}$ be the integral component and the remaining be the derivative component

Comment: Do I solve $I_n$ by itself or simplify LHS?

Comment: That should work, then. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'll give it one more try; I'll respond in two minutes

Comment: The problem is that, by simplifying LHS into one integral, then applying integration by parts with $2x e^{x^2}$ being the integral component, I get another integral which just decreases the exponent of $x$ into $x^{n-4}$ and $x^{n-6}$ and so on.

Comment: see my answer (I'm trying to see where I miscalculated, as I don't get exactly the same answer as expected -- the factor $2$ is not where it should according to your question).

Comment: I remember the teacher clarifying at the end of the lesson that the answer is wrong. Sorry for not mentioning that. You are correct, but please refer to my comment.

Comment: Oh, thanks -- checking for $n=2$, the correct answer appears to be indeed $2I_n + (n-1)I_{n-2} = e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts: write
$$\begin{align}
2I_n &= \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\cdot 2x e^{x^2} dx = \left[ x^{n-1}e^{x^2} \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 (n-1)x^{n-2} e^{x^2} dx \\
&= 1\cdot e^1 - 0\cdot 1 - (n-1)I_{n-2} = e - (n-1)I_{n-2}
\end{align}$$
so that, rearranging, 
$$
2I_n + (n-1)I_{n-2} = e
$$

Comment: Oh thanks, it seems much easier to do it by starting with $I_n$. But now I am wondering whether it is possible to do it by simplifying the LHS into one compound integral?

Comment: If you take $2 I_n + (n-1)I_{n-2}$, and write that as a single integral, you can write the integrand as $$x^{n-1}(2xe^{x^2}) + (n-1)x^{n-2}e^{x^2} = x^{n-1}\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^2} + e^{x^2}\frac{d}{dx} x^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx} (x^{n-1}e^{x^2}).$$

Comment: @mathsguyftw: as Daniel Fischer's comment shows, it is possible, but I'd say it's (a) not as easy (at least to me) as it relies more heavily on recognizing the right thing to do; and (b) it's not applicable if you are not sure about the actual recurrence relation to prove in the end.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I do agree that your way is more intuitive; and also as a side-note, which resources would you recommend to practice difficult integration questions?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't understand the 2nd part of the equation. The way I learnt integration by parts was:
$u dv = uv - v du$
How exactly would I correlate the second part of your equation to the method I use?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Wait I understand now, nevermind